# Binding data to a data grid column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

i'm new to WPF and i just learned today data binding, so i may have some basics errors.

**Goal :** 
I want a column in the data grid that will function like a combo box column that shows all the items from a string list.

XAML :

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn   Header="CitiesColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}/">
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind :

ObjectModel type :

```
class CitiesModel 
{
    private List<string> _Cities;
    public List<string> Cities { get { return _Cities; } set { _Cities = value ; } }
    public CitiesModel()
    {
        Cities = new List<string>
        {
            "Berlin",
            "Rome",
            "Paris",
            "Barcelona"
        }; 
    }
}
```

window.cs file :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CitiesModel Cm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Cm = new CitiesModel();
        DataContext = Cm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It shows no data at all not even a cell in the grid..
and when i tried the same code on a regular combo box it showed all of the data

XAML :

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"/>
```

I searched online and saw a way to do it with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`
instead of a ComboBox Column, and in this way i cant even see the column header.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Margin="44,65,52,-24" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Street Address">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of dozens of questions about the ComboBoxColumn ItemsSource binding...

Comment: You haven't even bound the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`, otherwise there won't even be any items.
2. The bindings in the data grid columns have a different `DataContext` than the grid itself, namely the context is the current row. So if you want to bind to another context you have to explicitly change the *binding source*.

Comment: thanks for the answer , i binded the ItemsSource of the data grid , and now i can see some cells, be still they are not binded to the Cities property , can you maybe show me  a small example of how to implement the 2 point you wrote?

Comment: No. Read the binding documentation/overview on MSDN or search stackoverflow, there are examples of just about anything here.